# Binary search on cstrings

Tags: c, binary-search

This implements binary search on an array of cstrings. One thing I'm wondering about is it faster or slower to pass a variable as `const` i.e. len. Also `strcmp()` gets called a lot and since I can't find any specific details on how it works, is it worthwhile to make my own function? For example does it immediately return a value if the first character of each arguments are different?

```
/*
*IN: scope: array of cstrings to be searched
*IN: len: length of array
*IN: find: cstring to be found
*OUT: true if find is in scope, otherwise false
*/
bool binSrch(char** scope, const int len, char* find)
{
   int c, first, last, middle;

   first = 0;
   last = len - 1;
   middle = (first+last)/2;

   while( first <= last )
   {
      if (strcmp(scope[middle], find) < 0 )
         first = middle + 1;
      else if (strcmp(scope[middle], find) == 0)
      {
         return true;
      }
      else
         last = middle - 1;

      middle = (first + last)/2;
   }
   if ( first > last )
      return false;
}
```

EDIT: is there a way to intelligently choose the pivot point? For example if your looking in a phone book for a name starting with Z you wouldn't start at the middle you'd start closer to the back.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about trying to understand the code snippet and not about seeking a review.

Comment: @Jamal this is my second post on this site so I'm still learning :) what makes you say I don't understand the code, the fact I point out some areas I see pitfalls? Would you rather I have posted just the code and not said anything?

Comment: It's working code, posted with some notes about concerns. I see nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: Okay, the latest edit did help.  Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assume that the implementation of `strcmp()` is not stupid.  A *lot* of code out there relies on `strcmp()`, so rest assured that a lot of work has gone into optimizing it.  Nevertheless, you don't want to call it twice per iteration through your loop.

Interestingly, `len` is the only parameter that doesn't need to be declared `const`, since it is passed by value.  In contrast, `scope` and `find` are passed by reference, so a promise that `binSrch()` won't alter them would be helpful.

At the end, you don't need to test for `first > last` before returning `false`.  The only way you can get past the `while` loop is with `first > last`.

You have an unused variable `c`.  Avoid such mistakes by getting into the habit of assigning right away:

```
int first = 0,
    last = len - 1,
    middle = (first + last) / 2;
```

I think the braces on your `else if` look weird.  Either remove them, or put them everywhere consistently.  (I prefer the latter.)

Comment: "promise that binSrch() won't alter them would be helpful" I could use a refresher on this, so if a pointer is passed as const that means the value it points to doesn't change right? Or does it mean the address the pointer points to doesn't change?

Comment: It [depends on where you put the `const`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6407041/1157100). In your case, feel free to sprinkle `const` liberally, since you never mutate anything. `bool binSrch(char const *const *scope, int len, char const* find)` would work.

Comment: Right so since I'm not changing the value or address pointed two should I use two `const` on each variable e.g. `char const * const find`? Perhaps that's a question by itself...

Comment: `char const * const find` would be a bit like `const int len` — correct, but superfluous and unimportant from the caller's point of view.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:

- I don't much like double pointers so I would probably define a type to be passed:

  ```
  typedef const char* String;
  ```

  Then let's define the function

  ```
  int binSrch(const String *list, size_t len, const char *find)
  ```

  You can still pass an array of char* to this.  I have added some `const`, used `size_t` for the array length (which is common with standard library functions) and replaced the `bool` with an `int` - which I prefer.
- Your code duplicates this line:

  ```
  middle = (first+last)/2;
  ```

  and uses different spacing for each.  Just do it once.
- Your brackets are inconsistent. I prefer to see brackets even when not strictly needed.
- Your duplicate `strcmp` calls should be removed.

Here is how it ends up:

```
int binSrch(const String *list, size_t len, const char *find)
{
  int start = 0;
  int end = len;
  while (start < end) {
      int middle = (start + end) / 2;
      int comp = strcmp(list[middle], find);
      if (comp < 0 ) {
          start = middle + 1;
      }
      else if (comp > 0) {
          end = middle;
      }
      else return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```